# Negated argument of the Heaviside Step Function

Tags: functions

If $H(x)$ is the Heaviside step function, what is $H(-x)$? Is it $-H(x)$ or 
does
$$H(-x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
1 & x < 0 \\
1/2 & x = 0 \\ 
0 & x > 0
\end{array}\right. \hspace{5ex}?$$

Comment: $1 - H(x)$  labhvljaehbgvlzd

Comment: @WillJagy: Thanks. May I ask what the letters following $1-H(x)$ mean?

Comment: A comment box demands a minimum of 15 characters, I put in blanks but it refused. Let me see if pairs of braces work, I think I have seen that used to make up the 15  {}{}{}{}{}{}{}  edit: evidently they do not disappear

Comment: @Will: enclose them in dollar signs: `${}{}{}{}$` then they do disappear.

Comment: @t.b. thanks. There is always one more gimmick to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we use the convention
$$H(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & x < 0 \\
1/2 & x = 0 \\
1 & x > 0
\end{cases}$$
it is straightforward to work out that 
$$H(-x) = 1-H(x),$$
which is equivalent to your second guess. 
Notice that $H(x)$ is not an odd function.

*Addendum*: 
In terms of the Iverson bracket,
$$ [P] = \begin{cases}
1, & \textrm{If }P\textrm{ is true} \\
0, & \textrm{otherwise},
\end{cases}$$
the Heaviside step function is 
$$H(x) = [x>0]+\frac{1}{2}[x=0].$$
There are different conventions for $H(0)$. 
Here we choose $H(0) = 1/2$. 
The properties of the Iverson bracket we will exploit here are $[\neg P] = 1-[P]$ and $[x<a]+[x=a] = [x\leq a]$. 
We find 
$$\begin{align}
H(-x) &= [-x>0] + \frac{1}{2}[-x=0] \\
&= [x<0] + \frac{1}{2}[x=0] \\
&= [x\leq 0] - \frac{1}{2}[x=0] \\
&= [\neg(x>0)] - \frac{1}{2}[x=0] \\
&= 1-[x>0] - \frac{1}{2}[x=0] \\
&= 1-H(x).
\end{align}$$

Comment: @J.M.: Thanks for the help. Why doesn't that LaTeX work?

Comment: I quite like the identity $H(x)=\dfrac{x+|x|}{2x}$ myself... thus, $\dfrac{-x+|-x|}{2(-x)}=\dfrac{x-|x|}{2x}=\dfrac{2x-(|x|+x)}{2x}=1-\dfrac{|x|+x}{2x}$

Comment: (As for the $\LaTeX$, I'm not sure why. At least `\begin{cases}` does...)

Comment: @J.M.: Very nice. By the way, I first learned of the Iverson bracket reading one of your answers. They're great! Maybe I'll try and get cases to work.

Comment: I'm happy that you are now using Iverson brackets because of something I wrote. Please do spread the word. ;)

Comment: @J.M.: I think the LaTeX problem was math in \textrm{...}.